# javascript: use of 'this' in object literal function giving an error

Tags: javascript

I'm having to fix up a megamenu system for a site I've been handed, and I've run into a bug.

Once the DOM is ready (jQuery is included) the megamenu's render function is run. Within this there a listener is added for resize to rerun this function, re-rendering the code. However, I'm getting javascript errors that think that this render function when called from within the object is actually a function of the window so I get **"Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'render'"**.

But the function runs anyway!

here's a brief snapshot of the code:

```
var jkmegamenu=
{
 ...
    render:function($)
    {
    ...
        $(window).bind("resize", function()
        {
          this.render($);
        }

    }

}
```

Now I've tried **jkmegamenu.render($)** (don't know what the dollar is for, works with or without due to jQuery I imagine), and I've tried defining self as **self: this** but the same error occurs. Its a fairly large file and I'm pretty busy so I'm only considering recoding it a proper jQuery object (e.g. http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/) if thats the only other option, otherwise does anyone know a quick fix?

The site is kent.ac.uk and you'll be able to see the errors popping up, especially on resize.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this` in JavaScript is a bit different than you may be used to from some other languages like C++, C#, or Java. It's defined entirely by *how a function is called*, not *where the function is defined.* More here: [You must remember `this`](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)

In your case, if you want to ensure that `this` refers to your `jkmegamenu` instance, you could use jQuery's [`proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) function, which will create a closure for you behind-the-scenes that calls your function with the correct "context" (`this` value):

```
var jkmegamenu=
{
 ...
    render:function($)
    {
    ...
        $(window).bind("resize", $.proxy(function()
        {
          this.render($);
        }, this));
    }

}
```

Or just use your own closure directly:

```
var jkmegamenu=
{
 ...
    render:function($)
    {
    ...
        var inst = this; // Remember `this`
        $(window).bind("resize", function()
        {
          // Use it
          inst.render($);
        });
    }

}
```

...which has the advantage that you can then use `this` to refer to the DOM object you hooked the event handler to (okay, so less useful for `window`, but quite useful when binding to other objects).

Closures are an extremely useful way of handling events. More here: [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)

For your situation, since `jkmegamenu` is a singleton, I'd probably just use the module pattern and not worry about `this` at all:

```
var jkmegamenu = (function() {
    var inst = {};

    // ...

    inst.render = jkmegamenu_render;
    function jkmegamenu_render($)
    {
        $(window).bind("resize", function()
        {
          inst.render($);
          // Or just jkmegamenu_render($);
        });
    }

    // Could have some private functions here, just by
    // virtue of not adding them to `inst`

    // ...

    return inst;
})();
```

That has the advantage of also giving your functions *names*, which [helps your tools help you](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/anonymouses-anonymous.html), and lets you have truly private functions as well.

You can also apply this pattern to factory functions ("classes" some would call them, although JavaScript doesn't have classes), with a bit of tweaking.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript acts a little differently than you'd expect, in the sense  that 'this' refers to whatever functional scope it is currently in.  So 'this' does not point to what you'd expect.  Instead, use:

```
var jkmegamenu=
{
 ...
    render:function($)
    {
    ...
        var that = this;
        $(window).bind("resize", function()
        {
          that.render($);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: JavaScript is **not** broken. It works *differently* than you're used to, but that's not *broken*.

Comment: Broken may be a bit harsh, I admit, but many people believe that javascript should not behave this way.  If you read 'Javascript: The Good Parts', Douglas Crockford makes the same claim (along with a few others).  I'll change my wording a bit though if it bugs people :)

Comment: Crockford makes lots of claims. Some of them are very good points. Some are not. I always say it's important to read Crockford -- and then to come to your *own* conclusions. ;-) I quite like the freedom and flexibility JavaScript provides.

Comment: you should also change where you say *'this' refers to whatever functional scope it is currently in*. A function's this keyword has nothing to do with scope, it is set by the caller and can reference any object the caller wants it to. Often it is the object that a function is called as a method of, or in a listener, the element that the listener is on. But they are just common cases and are by no means fixed or (in the case of listeners) consistent across browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Within your resize function, the `this` keyword refers to the DOM object being resized.

If you want to use the `this` object from the parent function, your best bet is to create a temporary variable pointing to `this` in the parent function. That variable will then be available in the scope of your resize function.

For more on how Javascript's `this` works, see this article: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/understanding-javascripts-this/